# Obtain alpha from Bootstrap Colorpicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I'm using [Bootstrap Colorpicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/) in my Rails project and wanted to get the *alpha* in my JavaScript function. Does anyone know how to do this? I can easily get the color from the picker as illustrated in the example as:

```
$(function(){
  var bodyStyle = document.getElementById('body').style;

  $('#cp4').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
    bodyStyle.backgroundColor = ev.color.toHex();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the alpha value as easily :) You have it in the color object: `ev.color.value.a`

I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLFdb/) illustrating this. The code looks as follows:

```
$('#picker').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
    alpha = ev.color.value.a;
    console.log(alpha);
    $('#alpha').append(alpha  + '</br>')
});​
```

The `alpha`variable is a `number` with the alpha value of the selected color.